# Is there any SQL code to remove overlapping continuous date span per customer code?

Tags: sql-server

Here is the sample question

```
id  customercode    start date  enddate
1   122 20200605    20200608
2   122 20200609    20200612
3   122 20200614    20200618
4   144 20200803    20200817
5   144 20200805    20200816
```

The output should be

```
customercode    start date  enddate 
122             20200605    20200612
122             20200614    20200618
144              20200803   20200817
```

I tried the following code.

```
select Customercode, min(startdate) as startdate, max(enddate) as enddate
from (
      select Customercode,  startdate, enddate
             sum(rst) over (order by Customercode, DOS) as grp
      from (
             select Customercode, startdate, enddate
                    case when coalesce(lag(enddate) over (partition by Customercode order by Customercode, startdate), startdate) + 1 <> startdate then 1 end rst
             from   tbl
           ) t1
     ) t2
group by grp, Customercode
order by startdate
```

The result is

| [customercode | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 122 | 20200605 | 20200612 |
| 122 | 20200614 | 20200618 |
| 144 | 20200803 | 20200817 |
| 144 | 20200805 | 20200816 |

How to remove the overlapping recordS ? Please share your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I understood.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you simply want aggregation with `min()` and `max()`.

```
SELECT customercode,
       min(startdate) startdate,
       max(enddate) enddate
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY customercode;
```

Comment: I was just wondering if there is any way to remove overlapping records from the table.